# checkbox binding not working in dynamic created column

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, dynamic-columns

In my angular app, I'm creating table dynamically from javascript.

```
$("#tableName").html("<table id='dtData' name='dtData' dt-options='dtOptions' dt-columns='dtColumns' class='table table-striped table-bordered'></table>");
```

here is how I'm generating columns

```
var header = data[0], dtColumns = [];

          //create columns based on first row in dataset
          for (var key in header) 
          {
             // console.log(key);
              if(key == "sendEmail")
              {
                  dtColumns.push(DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(key).withTitle("Send Email").renderWith(actionsHtml));

              }
              else
              {
                dtColumns.push(DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(key).withTitle(key));
              }
          }
```

this is `actionsHtml` function

```
    function actionsHtml(data, type, full, meta) {

    return '<input type="checkbox" name="sendEmail" value="' + data+'">';
}
```

And here I'm finalizing this table

```
 $scope.dtColumns = dtColumns;

          //create options
          $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
            .withOption('data', data)
            .withOption('dataSrc', '');

          //initialize the dataTable
          angular.element('#dtData').attr('datatable', '');
          $compile(angular.element('#dtData'))($scope);
```

It creates table and then a column of checkbox type but it doesn't bind value to checkbox. Here is table 
[image: Column]

and console value of column

[image]

But the problem is.. chechbox column binding is not working.. either I check/uncheck it from html or in javascript, it does not make any change in table/ original list.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Any chance you could make a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/) demonstrating the issue?

Comment: actually am too bad to make a plunker but I try

Comment: Use `checked` attribute instead of `value` ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox)). You compile the template but there's no binding in it so binding doesn't work, use ng-bing or ng-checked instead of `+ data +`.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by simple if/else of your data.. if data is `true`, add `checked` property else not. And then capture `onClick` event and pass some kind of `Id` to that function and update values accordingly..

Something like this

```
if(key == "SendEmail")
{                   

dtColumns.push(DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(key).withTitle("Send Email")
.renderWith(function(data, type, full, meta) {
if(data){
            return '<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="SendEmail" onClick="SendEmail_Clicked('+Id+')">'; 
        }
else
    {
        return '<input type="checkbox"  name="SendEmail"  onClick="SendEmail_Clicked('+Id+')">'; 
    }
}));}
```

To call `SendEmail_Clicked`, you first have to bind it with calling function, otherwise it will not work

```
var dt = this;
dt.SendEmail_Clicked = SendEmail_Clicked;
```

For more details, [you can read this](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/rowSelect)

Comment: The mentioned link helped me a lot. Thanks!